# Savon, Wasabi Error when connecting a Ruby script to a SOAP url

Tags: ruby, httpclient, savon, wasabi

Im trying to connect to a SOAP URL with a Ruby script.

I am following [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/290-soap-with-savon) Railscasts episode. I installed the savon gem(savon (2.4.0)).

Then in my ruby file I have this code:

```
 require 'savon'

 client = Savon.client(wsdl:"https://api.comscore.com/KeyMeasures.asmx?WSDL")
 response = client.call(:authenticate , message: { username:"xxxxx", password:"xxxxx"})

 puts "#{response.inspect}"
```

I know there is no issue with the url because I used [SOAPUI](http://www.soapui.org/About-SoapUI/what-is-soapui.html) and placed the WSDL URL there and I got back a response.

When I run the ruby file above I get the following exception:

```
  /Users/XXXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/wasabi-3.2.3/lib/wasabi/resolver.rb:44:in `load_from_remote': Error: 401 (Wasabi::Resolver::HTTPError)
from /Users/XXXXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/wasabi-3.2.3/lib/wasabi/resolver.rb:32:in `resolve'
```

After googling about I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18743570/ruby-savon-authentication) post, which seems to suggest that I should install and require gem "httpclient" which I did and then tried again.  No changes, Still getting the same error.

Can someone give me a hand as to how to proceed .....

Thanks

Comment: Does the Savon's created envelope match SOAP UI's created one? Specifically the authentification part.

Comment: How do I check Savon's created envelope?

Comment: Well, when you execute `client.call` e.g. in your console, don't you see an output like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope ...` ?

Comment: I have the above code in a *.rb file. I invoke the script at the command line. The first thing I see after is the error. I do not get any response back.

Comment: In your tags you mentioned `ruby-on-rails`, so run `rails console` and from there create the `client` and execute the `client.call`, because that error is related to response not the request. I don't know how else to get the request's output. :)

Comment: The error is thrown from Wasabi. Im digging through the source code now. On this link, the error is thrown at line 44:
https://github.com/savonrb/wasabi/blob/master/lib/wasabi/resolver.rb#L40
The error code of the response is 401, which means there is something going on with the authentication headers being rejected. I know the authentication works with SOAPUI, Ive tested it and gotten a response back. Its just not working with Savon. This means that maybe my syntax is wrong with Savon or more likely there is something to do with Wasabi and httpclient.

Comment: Here is the same issue being discussed:https://github.com/savonrb/savon/issues/504

Comment: I had same issue with https request. and adding 'httpclient' gem is really fixed it.

Comment: I was getting this error because I was sending my authenticated request (with a Bearer token) to a wrong endpoint, which does not use authentication, although is listening for the same kind of SOAP requests (same application).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried to access the WSDL you provided using `curl` from the commandline. I cannot access the  WSDL b/c I'm not authorized. I guess that first you have to provide the credentials as part of your https request. That's why `wasabi`fails. It cannot find the WSDL document.

According to the documentation that can be done by injecting the following code into your client creation:

```
client = Savon.client(wsdl: ...,
                      basic_auth: [ 'username', 'password' ],
                      log: true,
                      log_level: :debug,
                      pretty_print_xml: true)
client.call(...)
```