# How to Add authorization to none to access SOAP webservice in Ruby

Tags: ruby, soap

I try to access a SOAP webservice from ruby with Savon. Accessing this webservice raises a `Wasabi::Resolver::HTTPError`

I found that this is due to authorization issue. How do I set authorization to none in Ruby?

```
client = Savon.client(wsdl:"WSDL",ssl_verify_mode: :none)
```

Comment: In web services authorization is handled by the server, not the client. The code you are pasting is for the client. If you do not have permissions over the server there is nothing you can (or at least should) do to bypass authentication / authorization. Try to debug which HTTP Status Code the server is returning. Codes 401 and 403 mean lack of permissions. If you do have valid credentials for the service just call the authentication method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22990936/savon-wasabi-error-when-connecting-a-ruby-script-to-a-soap-url

Comment: Refer to the above post. i don't have credentials. so i want to bypass my authorization. There is Noauthorization option in SOAP . how can we use such an option?

Comment: Does the service you are trying to access allow unsigned requests? Try to provide more information about the service you are trying to access and HTTP response codes. If you are getting an unauthorized response and do not have valid credentials there is not much you can do.